How to prevent nicematrix from intersecting brackets of submatrices?
I am trying to set a blockvector A in another vector with brackets around A.
In the nicematrix documentation, there are ways described to set brackets around a part of a bigger matrix and to define subblocks, but it doesn't seem to work well together, the brackets for the inner and outer matrix are overlapping.
Here's a mwe:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \Block{3-1}{A} \\ \\ \\ 
            \CodeAfter
            \SubMatrix({4-1}{6-1})
    \end{pNiceMatrix} 
\]

\end{document}


How can you prevent the brackets from intersecting?

Similar to the example on p. 37 of the nicematrix user guide, you could add some extra margins to avoid the collision:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[right-margin=1em,left-margin=1em]
        0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \Block{3-1}{A} \\ \\ \\ 
            \CodeAfter
            \SubMatrix({4-1}{6-1})
    \end{pNiceMatrix} 
\]

\end{document}



That did it, and was also pretty straightforward in hindsight. Thanks!

@raph-jms You're welcome!
